# parsing a JSON containing several stringified jsons using Batch and JQ

Tags: json, batch-file, jq, text-parsing

I am creating an integration between two websites my company uses to track data. The API for one of the sites (Monday.com) has returned a json with several smaller json values stored as strings inside of it. I am having trouble parsing these values without calling fromjson individually on every single value.

The json I am receiving is formatted like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "percentage": "\"80\"",
    "Status": "{\"index\":1,\"post_id\":null,\"changed_at\":\"2019-07-29T14:44:50.305Z\"}",
    "Timeline": "{\"from\":\"2019-07-03\",\"to\":\"2019-07-25\",\"changed_at\":\"2019-07-29T14:55:39.487Z\"}",
    "Interview Done": "{\"date\":\"2019-07-03\",\"changed_at\":\"2019-07-23T19:56:01.004Z\"}",
    "Credentials Done": "{\"date\":\"2019-07-02\",\"changed_at\":\"2019-07-23T19:57:39.021Z\"}",
    "Skills Done": "{\"date\":\"2019-07-24\",\"changed_at\":\"2019-07-23T19:55:10.847Z\"}",
    "orientation Date": "{\"date\":\"2019-07-25\",\"changed_at\":\"2019-07-23T19:55:07.670Z\"}",
    "Hire Date": null
  },
  {
    "name": "yyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "percentage": null,
    "Status": "{\"index\":1,\"post_id\":null,\"changed_at\":\"2019-07-26T22:57:31.250Z\"}",
    "Timeline": "{\"from\":\"2019-07-17\",\"to\":\"2019-07-26\",\"changed_at\":\"2019-07-23T20:13:58.253Z\"}",
    "Interview Done": "{\"date\":\"2019-07-17\",\"changed_at\":\"2019-07-23T20:13:03.218Z\"}",
    "Credentials Done": "{\"date\":\"2019-07-24\",\"changed_at\":\"2019-07-25T16:12:40.484Z\"}",
    "Skills Done": "{\"date\":\"2019-07-17\",\"changed_at\":\"2019-07-23T20:13:29.884Z\"}",
    "orientation Date": "{\"date\":\"2019-07-25\",\"changed_at\":\"2019-07-23T20:11:52.848Z\"}",
    "Hire Date": null
  }
]
```

Is there a way to use a combination of Batch and jq in order to properly format this JSON as one large nested json, rather than a json containing several string formatted jsons?

I am struggling to parse the json dynamically as part of a batch script which fetches the json first, and then processes it before posting it to another API.

I have successfully parsed each thing individually using singular jq commands such as 
`myjson.json | jq . | jq .[].Timeline fromjson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest in your case would be to use `walk/1`:

```
walk( if type == "string" then fromjson? // . else . end)
```

### More generally ...

Sometimes it happens that applying `fromjson` just once is not enough.  In such cases, the following should be sufficient as it will cause the above procedure to be applied until quiescence:

```
def until_quiescence(f):
  (f as $x | if ($x == .) then . else ($x | until_quiescence(f)) end);

until_quiescence(walk( if type == "string" then fromjson? // . else . end) )
```

### walk/1

If your jq does not already have `walk`, simply include its def, which you can readily find e.g. by googling: jq "def walk"

Comment: This does work mostly, however it throws away my name field. Would there be a way to keep my name field by chance?

Comment: I've checked both versions (with and without `until_quiescence`) and the `name` field happily appears. Are you sure you are using `walk( if type == "string" then fromjson? // . else . end)`?

Comment: Ahh I did had not seen the // . pardon. My brain has subconsciously started tuning out // followed by comments. Thank you!